# Why does the output is not passing through the ability check in Role Based Authorization (One Role Per User)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

I want 3 user levels as Admin ,Manager,Customer in my rails application. So i've created a devise model as Users and added a migration to add the user role to it.So when a user is signed up it stores the users role(whether he is an admin,a manager or a customer). And in my application there are models and controllers for product,delivery,services. And I want to set access levels to each models.

So Admin have access to all models, controllers

Manager have access to Product, Delivery

Customer have access to Services

And i've written the Ability model as follows.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.roles == "admin"
      can :manage , :all
    elsif user.roles == "manager"
      can :read, Products, Delivery
    elsif user.roles == "customer"
      can :read, Services
    end
end
end
```

My show view for the product is as follows.

```
<% if can? :manage ,@products%>

<h1>Products</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<p>     <%= product.name%>
<p>         <%= product.price %><br>
<p>    <%= product.qty %><br>

  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

But even i sign in as an admin the data is not displayed.
I'm referring the following cancan documentation.
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization
The code seems to be okay with "One role per user"
But the data is not displayed.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: does @products have valid data?

Comment: yes.It has valid data.When i remove the ability check conditions it worked properly

Comment: does `user.roles == "admin"` log `true` in the console for that particular user ? you code seems to be fine otherwise.

Comment: This is the log record.----------------------------------------------------------------------> ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (7.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
  Rendering products/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (12.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 892ms (Views: 788.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the codes were correct but the issue was with the strong parameters.Therefor when signing up "role" has not saved in the database.Therefor when the ability is checked the users are not passed to view the content as non of they are admins,managers or customers

Answer (score 1):

I'm no real expert at CanCan, but You may try:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    cannot :manage, :all # we can do this since the abilities are OR'ed

    if user.roles.include?('admin')
      can :manage , :all
    elsif user.roles.include?('manager')
      can :read, Products, Delivery
    elsif user.roles.include?('customer')
      can :read, Services
    end
  end
end
```

Besides, if it's a project start, think about CanCanCan
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

It's updated version of CanCan, still maintained by the Community.